# Curl of vector fields in form $\begin{pmatrix}ax+by\\cx+dy\end{pmatrix}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-fields, curl

So I think I've got a misunderstanding about what curl is or made a calculation mistake. For the vector field $\begin{pmatrix}ax+by\\cx+dy\end{pmatrix}$ then its curl should be $\nabla \times \begin{pmatrix}ax+by\\cx+dy\end{pmatrix} = c-b$ which is a constant. For example $\nabla \times \begin{pmatrix}3x-3y\\-3x\end{pmatrix} = 0$. Which is a constant but the vector field looks like this:

[Image of vector field $\begin{pmatrix}3x-3y\\-3x\end{pmatrix}$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mG7hq.png)

This looks like at the bottom left and top right the curl should be positive and at the top and bottom the curl should be negative but the calculated curl is $0$ at all points.

What have I misunderstood about curl?

Comment: Why do you think the curl should be positive at points in the first quadrant? Here's how I think about curl. Pick a point $(x_0,y_0)$ in the first quadrant, then imagine a tiny circle enclosing $(x_0,y_0)$ that's allowed to rotate according to the nearby vectors of the vector field. It appears to me that the vectors in your example would "push" on both sides on the boundary of the circle in equal amounts, so a vanishing curl doesn't surprise me.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But it looks like in the bottom left and top right the arrows form like an anti-clockwise spiral and at the top and bottom a clockwise spiral. Doesn’t this mean curl?

Comment: Curl is a measure of counterclockwise "spin" at a *local* level, not a global one. As I mentioned above, you should try to envision a *tiny* circle subject to this vector field and then ask yourself in which direction would such a circle rotate. The vectors in the vector field you provide don't seem to encourage rotation in any direction.

Comment: I suggest you print off a copy of this vector field and then draw a tiny circle at a location of your choosing. Then ask yourself if vectors will make circle to rotate and in which direction. If it appears that the circle will rotate in a counterclockwise manner, this means you have positive curl where you drew the circle. If the circle will rotate in a clockwise manner, then you have negative curl where you drew the circle. No rotation indicates zero curl. Just by the looks of it, your tiny circle won't rotate, regardless of where you draw it.

Comment: Oooohhh!!! That makes so much sense. Thank you :)

Comment: @user429040 Since you explained it first, would you mind turning your comments into an answer so this doesn't stay unanswered?